# Use imported javascript function in HTML

Tags: javascript

What i'm trying to do is have a button that, when clicked, calls an ajax function that will add an element to the document. I started using modules in my project because I find it "cleaner" than just have files using the same scope, but i have a hard time understanding how some things works.

So I have something like this:

html:

```html
<button onclick="addEvent(this, dayPlanningId)"><span class="plusButton">+</span></button>

<script type="module" src="main.js">
```

main.js:

```js
import * as Ajax from "./ajax.js";
 // Some stuff
```

ajax.js:

```js
export function addEvent(addButton, dayPlanningId)
{
 // Some ajax stuff
}
```

So I try to use the function "addEvent" which is exported from "ajax.js", that I have imported in "main.js" which is itself imported in my HTML. When I try and click on my button, I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined
```

I tried to call "addEvent" using "Ajax.addEvent" as I store the imported function in an object called "Ajax" (from what I understood from the javascript documentation on import/export), but I got

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined
```

I tried re-exporting the ajax function with

```
export * as Ajax from "./ajax.js";
```

but it didn't work either using both of the previous syntax...

I'm short on idea, so anyone knows if what i'm trying to do is possible? Or I am just going the wrong way and there is an other way around to do the same thing?

EDIT: I know my code arrangement might not be optimal, but it is just a personnal project so it doesn't really matter

---

So if anyone stumble upon my post rather than the duplicate, the best answer I found so far is that I have to attach an event listener to my button from my main.js. This file imports my ajax function, so it will be useable in its scope only.

Comment: Well, you're writing `onclick="addEvent()"` just _before_ importing the script and declaring the addEvent function

Comment: @JeremyThille — That's irrelevent. The variable name isn't evaluated until the click event occurs.

Comment: @phuzi — It is loaded beforehand. (Because the thing it has to be "before" is the click event)

Comment: Since you're loading main.js after the HTML, it won't find it. Try moving the script tag above into the <head> or even better, leave it where it is, remove onclick from the DOM node and add the event listener to it in the JS

Comment: @Quentin ok, I suspected it but I wasn't sure

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias — No. It doesn't matter that the script is loaded after the HTML, just so long as it is loaded before the **click**.

Comment: Ok cool, we're saying the same thing